# Variable is empty in SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

My provider is

```
public Cursor query(Uri  uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    if(uriMatcher.match(uri) == TEXTS_ID)  
        selection = DBOpenHelper.text_ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment();
    return database.query(DBOpenHelper.TABLE_textS, DBOpenHelper.ALL_COLUMNS, selection, selectionArgs, null, null,DBOpenHelper.text_CREATED + " DESC");
}
```

I am calling this with:

```
String [] cursorArgs = new String [] {"0"};
String selection = "textId=";
return new CursorLoader(this, textsProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, cursorArgs, null);
```

As you see, I want text when my textId=0

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ORDER": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, textId, textText, textCreate FROM texts WHERE textId= ORDER BY textCreated DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selection is `SQLite` must have `?` after `=`, so try

```
String selection = "textId=?";
```